# Hello! I'm trying to insert rows in my mysql db using contact form 7

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to insert rows in my MySQL DB using contact form 7.
But it doesn't insert those elements, just five I see inserted.

Is there any limit for the array?
Tks a lot.

I'm using this code:

```
function contactform7_before_send_mail( $form_to_DB ) {
//set your db details
$mydb = new wpdb('test','test,','test','test');

$form_to_DB = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
if ( $form_to_DB ) 
    $formData = $form_to_DB->get_posted_data();

$localorigem = $formData['local-origem'];
$dataatendimento = $formData['data-atendimento'];
$numeroprontuario = $formData['numero-prontuario'];
$numerocartaosus = $formData['numero-cartao-sus'];
$nomeusuario = $formData['nome-usuario'];
$sexo = $formData['sexo'];
$gestante = $formData=['gestante'];
$idgestacional = $formData=['id-gestacional'];
$datanascimento = $formData=['data-nascimento'];
$estadocivil = $formData=['estado-civil'];
$racacor = $formData=['raca-cor'];
$escolaridadeanos = $formData=['escolaridade-anos'];
$ocupacaotexto = $formData=['ocupacao-texto'];

$mydb->insert(

        'test', array( 

        'local-origem' =>$localorigem, 
        'data-atendimento' =>$dataatendimento, 
        'numero-prontuario' =>$numeroprontuario, 
        'numero-cartao-sus' => $numerocartaosus, 
        'nome-usuario' => $nomeusuario, 
        'data-nascimento' => $datanascimento, 
        'id-gestacional' => $idgestacional,
        'data-nascimento' = $datanascimento,
        'estado-civil' = $estadocivil,
        'raca-cor' = $racacor,
        'escolaridade-anos' = $escolaridadeanos,
        'ocupacao-texto' = $ocupacaotexto

    ) );

}
remove_all_filters ('wpcf7_before_send_mail');
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'contactform7_before_send_mail' );
```

[image]

Comment: You are initialising your array wrong. Sometimes you use '=' instead of '=>'

Comment: Replace '=>' with '='

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change this. **UPDATED Answer**

```
 $gestante = $formData=['gestante'];
$idgestacional = $formData=['id-gestacional'];
$datanascimento = $formData=['data-nascimento'];
$estadocivil = $formData=['estado-civil'];
$racacor = $formData=['raca-cor'];
$escolaridadeanos = $formData=['escolaridade-anos'];
$ocupacaotexto = $formData=['ocupacao-texto'];
$mydb->insert(

        'test', array( 

        'local-origem' =>$localorigem, 
        'data-atendimento' =>$dataatendimento, 
        'numero-prontuario' =>$numeroprontuario, 
        'numero-cartao-sus' => $numerocartaosus, 
        'nome-usuario' => $nomeusuario, 
        'data-nascimento' => $datanascimento, 
        'id-gestacional' => $idgestacional,
        'data-nascimento' = $datanascimento,
        'estado-civil' = $estadocivil,
        'raca-cor' = $racacor,
        'escolaridade-anos' = $escolaridadeanos,
        'ocupacao-texto' = $ocupacaotexto

    ) );
```

To

```
 $gestante = $formData['gestante'];
$idgestacional = $formData['id-gestacional'];
$datanascimento = $formData['data-nascimento'];
$estadocivil = $formData['estado-civil'];
$racacor = $formData['raca-cor'];
$escolaridadeanos = $formData['escolaridade-anos'];
$ocupacaotexto = $formData['ocupacao-texto'];
$mydb->insert(

        'test', array( 

        'local-origem' =>$localorigem, 
        'data-atendimento' =>$dataatendimento, 
        'numero-prontuario' =>$numeroprontuario, 
        'numero-cartao-sus' => $numerocartaosus, 
        'nome-usuario' => $nomeusuario, 
        'data-nascimento' => $datanascimento, 
        'id-gestacional' => $idgestacional,
        'data-nascimento' => $datanascimento,
        'estado-civil' => $estadocivil,
        'raca-cor' => $racacor,
        'escolaridade-anos' => $escolaridadeanos,
        'ocupacao-texto' => $ocupacaotexto

    ) );
```

Comment: Yes!
I did this "=>", but the problem persists.

Comment: Now see updated answer and remove `=` from `$formData=['gestante']`